# rendering images XmlWorkerHelper(itextpdf)

Tags: itextpdf

please help me.

I have problem with rendering image in pdf
im usung itextpdf 5.5.6 and itext 5.5.6

my code is:

```
    .
    .
    .


    URL url = new URL("http://some.html");

    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
     XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

     worker.parseXHtml(pdrwriter, doc, inputStreamReader);

     doc.close();
        //close the writer
     pdrwriter.close();
```

my html has:

```
<table><tr><td><img src="http://mysite/logo.jpg" /></td</tr></table>
```

and i get error:
Invalid nested tag td found, expected closing tag img.

I have tried

```
<table><tr><td><img src="http://mysite/logo.jpg"></img</td</tr></table>
```

the sam error..

do You know how to handel it? Thx for help!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
<table><tr><td><img src="http://mysite/logo.jpg" /></td</tr></table>
```

It should be:

```
<table><tr><td><img src="http://mysite/logo.jpg" /></td></tr></table>
```

This is also wrong:

```
<table><tr><td><img src="http://mysite/logo.jpg"></img</td</tr></table>
```

It should be:

```
<table><tr><td><img src="http://mysite/logo.jpg"></img></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: heh, i made a mistake in my question, but is none, i have just pressed a wrong key.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML file you're parsing is stored in a directory that is different from the working directory, iText won't be able to create Image objects. We have to supply an implementation of the ImageProvider interface that tells iText what to do if an img tag is encountered. This interface has the following method.

```
Image retrieve(final String src);
String getImageRootPath();
void store(String src, Image img);
void reset();
```

You can write your own class implementing these four methods, or you can subclass AbstractImageProvider. It is preferred to do the latter.

XML Worker will use the store() method of the AbstractImageProvider class to cache all the Image objects that are encountered in a Map. These objects will be reused when the retrieve() method is called for an image with the same src. If you don't cache images, your PDF will be bloated. The same image bits and bytes will be written to the PDF more than once. The reset() method clears the cache; it is used when an ImageProvider is cloned. Finally, the getImageRootPath() method isn't implemented. You have to implement it yourself, as is done in the following snippet

```
htmlContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {

public String getImageRootPath() {

    return "src/main/resources/html/";

}
});
```